# how to pass additional data to the test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, functional-testing

please help solve the problem.

controller tags:

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
    @posts = @tag.posts
  end
end
```

test tags:

```
class TagsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  fixtures :tags, :posts

  setup do
    @tag = tags(:one)        
  end

  test "should get show" do
    get :show, :tag => @tag
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:tag)
    assert_template :show
    assert_template layout: "layouts/application"        
  end    

  test "should route to show tag posts" do
    assert_generates "/tags/@tag", controller: 'tags', action: 'show', id: "@tag"  # OK
  end  
end
```

fixtures tags:

```
one: 
  tagname: 'qwe'
```

fixtures posts:

```
one:
  title: 'MyString1'
  body: '1Lorem Ipsum'
  user: :one
  views: 2
```

after starting the test, I get the following error message:

> ```
>   1) Error:
> TagsControllerTest#test_should_get_show:
> ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tags", :tag=>"980190962"}
>     test/controllers/tags_controller_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:TagsControllerTest>'
> ```

please tell me how to pass @posts in my test. or tell me another solution

Models Tag and Post linked via HABTM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test case should pass `:id` instead of `:tag`. It should look like:

```
  test "should get show" do
    get :show, :id => @tag.id
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:tag)
    assert_template :show
    assert_template layout: "layouts/application"        
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
get :show, :tag => @tag
```

to

```
get :show, id: @tag.id
```